# SVN 1.8.9 with vmware shared folders

Tags: vmware, svn, sqlite

**This is my setup:**

- Running on a vmware debian wheezy
- Shared folder is on windows, accessed with vmware-tools
- I'm using the latest TortoiseSVN on the windows side of things, so downgrading svn is not really my favorite option

**This is the problem:**

When using svn up or almost any svn command, I get the following error:

> svn: E200030: sqlite[S10]: disk I/O error
>
> svn: E200030: Additional errors:
>
> svn: E200030: sqlite[S10]: disk I/O error

Then I have to perform a svn cleanup windows side with tortoise.

**I tried:**

- Using a precompiled svn 1.8.9 package (several available easily found)
- Compiling subversion myself with different versions of sqlite (from the earliest accepted 3.1.12 to the latest)

**What I think the problem is:**

The problem seems related to the locking mechanism of sqlite, which seems to be incompatible somehow with windows shares.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007024/cygwin-svn-e200030-sqlite-disk-i-o-error) for more info.

**Question:**

Do you have any idea of how I can make this setup work without downgrading tortoise and svn (and I'm not even sure that would work correctly, even if I think I remember it did)?

One thing of note is that the eclipse subversive plugin seems to be able to use svn 1.8 through the shared folders without any problem. This isn't really a subversion problem, so maybe there's a way of changing the locking mechanism of sqlite with a configure option or something? Anyway this is my next lead, but I hope someone here already made this work!

Thank you for your time!

*Update:* From the [sqlite doc](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) we can read: there are reports of locking problems for network filesystems under Windows. Your best defense is to not use SQLite for files on a network filesystem.

Well, ok.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question?